# Is there a way to automatically run select statement in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, scheduled-tasks, oracle-sqldeveloper

How or is there a way to automatically run my SELECT statement on a scheduled time? For example, I want my monitoring query to run every 1PM and 8PM. Since this will be done daily, can it be run automatically and just view the results from a csv/excel file or from the result tab? My tool is Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we **schedule** a database job. It can be done using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` (preferably, especially in latest database versions) or `DBMS_JOB` (simpler to use).

For example:

- create a stored procedure which does the job and inserts the result into some table
- schedule it to run at desired times
- don't forget to store the timestamp!
- any time you want, run `select * from some_table` to view the result

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can run them via [SQLPlus and spool](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm) to file. Create a shell script with SQL Plus code in your operating system and use you OS scheduler to run it periodically. Then you can open files and view results.